# How to differentiate between pointers to shared and global memory?

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

In CUDA, given the value of a pointer, or the address of a variable, is there an intrinsic or another API which will introspect which address space the pointer refers to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CUDA header file `sm_20_intrinsics.h` defines the function

```
__device__ unsigned int __isGlobal(const void *ptr)
{
  unsigned int ret;
  asm volatile ("{ \n\t"
                "    .reg .pred p; \n\t"
                "    isspacep.global p, %1; \n\t"
                "    selp.u32 %0, 1, 0, p;  \n\t"
#if (defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_WIN64)) || defined(__LP64__)
                "} \n\t" : "=r"(ret) : "l"(ptr));
#else
                "} \n\t" : "=r"(ret) : "r"(ptr));
#endif

  return ret;
}
```

This function returns `1` if generic address `ptr` is in global memory space.
It returns `0` if `ptr` is in shared, local or constant memory space.

The PTX instruction `isspacep` does the heavy lifting. It seems like we should be able to build the analogous function this way:

```
__device__ unsigned int __isShared(const void *ptr)
{
  unsigned int ret;
  asm volatile ("{ \n\t"
                "    .reg .pred p; \n\t"
                "    isspacep.shared p, %1; \n\t"
                "    selp.u32 %0, 1, 0, p;  \n\t"
#if (defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_WIN64)) || defined(__LP64__)
                "} \n\t" : "=r"(ret) : "l"(ptr));
#else
                "} \n\t" : "=r"(ret) : "r"(ptr));
#endif

  return ret;
}
```

### Update:

`__isGlobal()` and other *address space predicate functions* are described in the [CUDA C++ Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#address-space-predicate-functions).

Comment: Note that there is also `isspacep.local` for local memory.